# How to use Laravel Debugbar in controller?

Tags: laravel-5

I got an error `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Debugbar' not found` after trying to use in controller action `Debugbar::error('Error!');`

LARAVEL DEBUGBAR WAS INSTALED IN THIS WAY:

in console `composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`

in config/app.php adding `Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class` and `'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,`

Laravel 5.3

Debugbar is working in the website - I can see it at the bottom even after this error. But how to fix this critical error message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either explicitly use the Facade or use Debugbar from the root namespace.

```
\Debugbar::error('hi');

// OR
use \Debugbar;
Debugbar::error('hi');

// OR
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as Debugbar;
Debugbar::error('hi');
```

Comment: "use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as Debugbar;" I was using the wrong 'use' statement. This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: It works for me like this.

`use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facades\Debugbar;`

`Debugbar::info("this is working now");`

Thank anyways.